# Не подгружается полная картинка на сайт

Tags: php

Обычная галерея, при клике должна открываться картинка и количество просмотров, все работает, просмотры показывает, но картинка просто значек её, она не подгружается.
[image: к]
Вот код

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Галерея</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Gallery</h1>
</body>

</html>
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("my.loc", "root", "root", "gallery");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM img_props ORDER BY views desc");
while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $dir = 'images/';
  echo '<a href="fullsizeimg.php/?img_id=' . $rows["img_id"] . '"><img src=' . $dir . $rows["img_name"] . ' style="width: 200px;"></a>';
}
```

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['img_id']) && is_numeric($_GET['img_id']) && $_GET['img_id'] > 0) {
   $img_id = $_GET['img_id'];
   $link = mysqli_connect("my.loc", "root", "root", "gallery");
   if (!$link)
      echo mysqli_error($link) . mysqli_errno($link);
   $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM img_props WHERE img_id = $img_id");
   if (!$result)
      echo mysqli_error($link) . mysqli_errno($link);
   while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $dir = 'images/';
      echo '<img src=' . $dir . $rows["img_name"] . '>';
      echo '<h3>Число просмотров: ' . $rows["views"] . '</h3>';
   }
   $result2 = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE img_props SET views=views+1 WHERE img_id=$img_id");
   if (!$result2) echo mysqli_error($link) . mysqli_errno($link);
}
```

Comment: Что в инспекторе браузера было написано в консоле/сетях насчет той картинки? Проверили, что путь, по которому браузер обращается правильный?

Comment: Ошибку нашел $dir = 'images/' => $dir = '/images/'

Comment: Оформите ответ с указанием проблемы и ее решением ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибку нашел $dir = 'images/' => $dir = '/images/'